# PHP Read txt file and check if username password exists

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables, plaintext

I have a bunch of passwords and usernames stored in a txt file and i need to check for matches. I know this is not a safe method but its for leaning purposes.

This code writes the usernames and passwords to a txt file

```
  if(isset($_POST['register'])) //  
   {
    $user  = $_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'].PHP_EOL;
    $fh = fopen("file.txt","a+");
    fwrite($fh,$user." ".$password); //write to txtfile

    fclose($fh);
 }
```

Here's the code im having trouble with.

Username and Passwords are stored like this in results

```
      username1 passwords1 username2 password2 etc.
```

So I need to check if result[0] = userinput AND if it exists check if result[1] = passwordInput and so on.

```
   if(isset($_POST['Logg']))
   {
   //$_SESSION['username']=$user; 
   //$_SESSION['password']=$password;

    $file = file_get_contents("file.txt"); // Returns a string

    $result = explode(" ",$file);
    $boolC= false;

    for($i=0; $i< count($result); $i++)
    {
   if($result[$i] === $user)
   {
    $boolC=true;
    $i =$i+1; 
    if($boolC === true)
    {
        if($result[$i]===$password)
        {
            echo 'Password and Username Correct';
        }
    }

   }
     }

  }
```

Comment: If its not clear what im asking let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the possibility of having a space in the password so as any symbols. Perhaps you should split on a line break ("\n").

```
if( $result[$i] === $user && $result[$i+1] === $password )
```

The first part of the statement has to be true for the second one to be evaluated. 
The $i variable is never changed

```
$file = "username1 passwords1 username2 password2";
$result = explode(" ",$file);
$user = "username1";
$password = "passwords1";

for($i=0; $i< count($result); $i++){

    if($result[$i] === $user && $result[$i+1] === $password)
    {

        echo 'Password and Username Correct';
   }
}
```

Comment: I was going to post something similar. The only thing I would change is the loop increment (also a problem in the original post) to be as follows: for($i=0; $i< count($result); $i=$i+2). If we increment only 1 by 1, and a user happened to have a password that matches ANOTHER user's username, it would be interpreted as such, and the result would be incorrect. I.e: if the password file was: user1 hellokitty hellokitty pass2, then the user hellokitty would never be able to login.

Comment: Im getting errors Undefined variable on  if($result[$i] === $user && $result[$i+1] === $password)

Comment: Yes, after writing the stuff about the $i+2 and etc... I was like the heck with that he's writing emails and password in a text file!!!

Comment: @Sebastian did you manage to find which one of the $variables was causing the error, you could always produce `echo` statement to validate that what you assume to be present is really indeed there.

Comment: @kingdomcreation No i have not been able to resolve my problem, I'll keep looking.

Comment: I hope you were able to at least consider all our concerns, because like dcasadevall said if a password is the same as a username you will  never get it to match you password unless you iterate every other part of your string (just usernames)

Comment: @kingdomcreation The problem seems to be with reading from the text file. Your code works fine btw.

Comment: Were you open to rewrite your file with line breaks instead? @Sebastian can you confirm that the file was written and has the content in it.

Comment: @Yes That works fine. It seems to be a issue when i use explode it doesnt separate all pass and username. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: @ I found out the problem i think I need to explode through "\n" then explode the result array value through space.

Comment: Here's a link to my updated code doesnt produce any errors but the validation doesnt work. http://codepad.org/v6njjgfU

Answer (score 1):

Before you go ahead and try to correct this code, I strongly suggest you stay away from storing passwords in a plain text file. It is a huge security hole in your system.

Another architecture issue I can see is that your code would fail if the username or passwords contain a space in them. You probably should use line jumps as a delimiter instead (\n).

Comment: I know  its not safe to store usernames and passwords in a txt file, but its for leaning purposes so it doesnt matter. Regarding that the code will fail if i contains a space we can disregard that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with the logic of the original post.

You should print all the variables to check whether they hold the correct value or not.

the "$user" and "$password" variables are global or not since they would not be known within the braces of the other if block i.e in the block where you check $_POST['logg']

Comment: In other words , i simply wanna ask where are the $user and $password variables declared or initialized?

Comment: They are declared where i write to the txt file.

Comment: then check if they are available at the place where you use these variables i.e in the if blocks.
getting?