# PHP Login form without DB and more then one name/passwords

Tags: php, security

I have a PHP app where I'm trying to read two files (userdata.txt & passwords.txt). When somebody signs up, the information is sent in the form of these 2 files (with file_put_contents).

Now, how do I read each one's name/pass from these 2 files?

```
if ($_SESSION['isLogged'] == true) {
    echo '<a href="./destroy.php">Exit</a>';
    header('Location: profile.php');

} else {
    if ($_POST) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username1']);
        $pass = trim($_POST['password1']);
        $regnames= fopen('userdata.txt');
        $readname = fread($regname,'r');
        $regpass= fopen('passwords.txt');
        $readpass = fread($regpass,'r');

        if ($_POST['username']==$readname && ($_POST['password']==$readpass)) {
            header ('Location: profile.php');
            exit;
        }

        else {
            echo '<p class=" content alert alert-danger">Error data</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's some examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: This is a similar example of what your attempting to do. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189470/php-read-txt-file-and-check-if-username-password-exists

Comment: `wget http://yoursite.com/usernames.txt` and `wget http://yoursite.com/passwords.txt` oh and they're in plaintext too! Sweet. Seriously, don't do this.

Comment: In addition to Sammith's comment, even if you make the data files inaccessible via the webserver and use salted hashes for passwords you are still heading for a world of pain with memory and concurrency management. There are lots of reasons why database management systems exist.